# Need to access Outlook contact details from multiple Mail IDs using C#

Tags: c#, outlook-2007

Using an application, I'm fetching the contact details stored in the Micosoft Office Outlook using C#. I achieved it through the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` namespace.

The issues I'm facing now is when Outlook has multiple mail IDs configured to the same system I need to fetch contacts of the Individual mail IDs seperately.
How do I do this?

Here is the sample code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Getting the contacts by passing the folder name.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="folderName"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private List<MyContact> GetContactsFromFolder(string folderName)
{
    List<MyContact> contacts = null;
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    //Create instance of Outlook application and Outlook Contacts folder.
    try
    {
        OutLook.MAPIFolder fldContacts = null;
        contacts = new List<MyContact>();
        OutLook._Application outlookObj = new OutLook.Application();
        /* if (folderName == "Default")
        {
            fldContacts = (OutLook.MAPIFolder)outlookObj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
        }
        else
        {
            OutLook.MAPIFolder contactsFolder = (OutLook.MAPIFolder)
            outlookObj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            //VERIFYING THE CUSTOM FOLDER IN OUT LOOK .
            foreach (OutLook.MAPIFolder subFolder in contactsFolder.Folders)
            {
                if (subFolder.Name == folderName)
                {
                    fldContacts = subFolder;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        * */

        fldContacts = (OutLook.MAPIFolder)outlookObj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

        //LOOPIN G THROUGH CONTACTS IN THAT FOLDER.
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem contactItem in fldContacts.Items)
        {
            MyContact contact = new MyContact();

            contact.FromAddress = contactItem.SenderEmailAddress;
            contact.ToAddress = contactItem.To;
            contact.Subject = contactItem.Subject;
            contact.MailSize = contactItem.Size.ToString();
            contact.Received = contactItem.ReceivedTime.ToString();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
            con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Initial Catalog=sample;Integrated Security=True;Server=Test;Connect Timeout=900";
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                string to_address = "";
                string Cc = "";

                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient olRecipient in contactItem.Recipients)
                {
                    if (contactItem.To.ToLower().Contains(olRecipient.Address.ToLower()) == true ||
                        contactItem.To.ToLower().Contains(olRecipient.Name.ToLower()) == true)
                    {
                        if (to_address != "")
                        {
                            to_address = to_address + ";" + olRecipient.Name + " <" + olRecipient.Address + ">";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            to_address =olRecipient.Name+" <"+olRecipient.Address+">";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        if (contactItem.CC != null && contactItem.CC.ToString() != "")
                        {
                            if (contactItem.CC.ToLower().Contains(olRecipient.Address.ToLower()) == true ||
                                contactItem.CC.ToLower().Contains(olRecipient.Name.ToLower()) == true)
                            {
                                if (Cc != "")
                                {
                                    Cc = Cc + ";" + olRecipient.Name + " <" + olRecipient.Address + ">";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Cc = olRecipient.Name + " <" + olRecipient.Address + ">";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
                //contact.
                contacts.Add(contact);
            }
        }
```

Comment: please show us some code. Depending on the way you are doing right now, some changes could be required because you should not always and only open the main or default user's folder.

Answer (score 0):

The point is in this call of your code:

```
fldContacts = (OutLook.MAPIFolder)outlookObj.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

Here you are always opening the default folder.

You should try to enumerate the available folders and call another method of the `Session` object to open the one you need to use.

I don't know the answer right now, but this is the direction to go.

Comment: i have used the subFolder also, for testing i have commented the block of code. The issue is in accessing multiple Id's